# When is the profinite completion of a Noetherian group ring also Noetherian?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, topological-groups, profinite-groups, group-rings

Let $G$ be a group, and let $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ denote its group ring. Its profinite completion is the inverse limit over all ideals of finite index. By [Benjamin Steinberg's answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261479/difference-between-the-completed-group-algebra-and-the-profinite-completion-of-a), this profinite completion agrees with the completed group algebra $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}[[\widehat{G}]]$, where $\widehat{G}$ denotes the profinite completion of $G$.

I say that a profinite ring $\Lambda$ is Noetherian if every closed submodule of a topologically finitely generated $\Lambda$-module is (topologically) finitely generated. (This seems to be weaker than the ACC for closed ideals!)

Now assume that $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ is Noetherian (As @YCor points out, [this implies that $G$ is noetherian and amenable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165039/does-gl-nz-have-a-noetherian-group-ring/165065#165065)). When can we conclude that its profinite completion (equivalently $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}[[\widehat{G}]]$) is also Noetherian?

I'm especially interested in the case where $G$ is finitely generated and abelian. Even the case $G = \mathbb{Z}^r$ would be interesting to me.

Comment: The only groups $G$ for which $Z[G]$ is known to be noetherian are virtually polycyclic groups. (Conversely, if $Z[G]$ is noetherian, it is known that $G$ is noetherian and amenable. [See this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/165065/14094))

Comment: How can we describe that completed ring for $G = \mathbb{Z}$ more concretely?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg The completed ring for $G = \mathbb{Z}$ is described [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261482/is-widehat-mathbbzt-cong-widehat-mathbbz-widehat-mathbbz?rq=1). It is the product of $\mathbb{Z}_q[[t]]$, where each $q$ is a prime power and the corresponding direct factor appears multiple times (number of times is equal to the number of Frobenius orbits on $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$). It certainly does not satisfy ACC, but this doesn't necessarily mean that there exists an infinitely generated closed ideal, since the union of the ascending chain may not be closed.